# embed synchronous python code with Asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

This script below is some example code from the [open leader project](https://openleadr.org/) that uses `iohttp` and `asyncio` for a client server XML based web protocol communication process for the utility industry.

Newbie question here, is it possible to embed synchronous code with asynchronous code? For example this code here which is embeded into the `main.py` below I know is *definitely* synchronous. Its BACnet communication library with [BAC0](https://bac0.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
bacnet = BAC0.lite()


async def collect_report_value():
    #read temp sensor from BACnet device
    T1 = bacnet.read('12345:2 analogInput 2 presentValue')
    return T1
```

The `main.py` script works (shown below) I can `#read temp sensor from BACnet device` from the async function `collect_report_value` I am just worried that I could possibly be making the entire process synchronous. Would anyone have any advice?

```
import asyncio
from datetime import timedelta
from openleadr import OpenADRClient, enable_default_logging
import BAC0



bacnet = BAC0.lite()


async def collect_report_value():
    #read temp sensor from BACnet device
    T1 = bacnet.read('12345:2 analogInput 2 presentValue')
    return T1

async def handle_event(event):
    # This callback receives an Event dict.
    # You should include code here that sends control signals to your resources.
    return 'optIn'

# Create the client object
client = OpenADRClient(ven_name='ven123',
                       vtn_url='http://localhost:8080/OpenADR2/Simple/2.0b')

# Add the report capability to the client
client.add_report(callback=collect_report_value,
                  resource_id='device001',
                  measurement='temperature',
                  sampling_rate=timedelta(seconds=60))

# Add event handling capability to the client
client.add_handler('on_event', handle_event)

# Run the client in the Python AsyncIO Event Loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(client.run())
loop.run_forever()
```

***EDIT*** final script that appears to work

```
import asyncio
from datetime import timedelta
from openleadr import OpenADRClient, enable_default_logging
import BAC0
import concurrent.futures

enable_default_logging()


#apprently runs on its own thread
bacnet = BAC0.lite()


def blocking_io():
    #read temp sensor from BACnet device
    try:
         sensor_value = bacnet.read('12345:2 analogInput 2 presentValue')
         return sensor_value
    except:
         return np.nan


async def collect_report_value():
    # 1. Run in the default loop's executor:
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_io)
    return result



async def handle_event(event):
    # This callback receives an Event dict.
    # You should include code here that sends control signals to your resources.
    return 'optIn'

# Create the client object
client = OpenADRClient(ven_name='ven123',
                       vtn_url='http://localhost:8080/OpenADR2/Simple/2.0b')

# Add the report capability to the client
client.add_report(callback=collect_report_value,
                  resource_id='device001',
                  measurement='temperature',
                  sampling_rate=timedelta(seconds=60))

# Add event handling capability to the client
client.add_handler('on_event', handle_event)

# Run the client in the Python AsyncIO Event Loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(client.run())
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Yes, look up [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools), which is provided for exactly that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Would you be able to recommend a preferred option? Or does it really matter much? Options 1,2,3 are `Run in the default loop's executor`, `Run in a custom thread pool` , `Run in a custom process pool`? I really need to know more about this stuff any tips greatly appreciated!

Comment: Option #1 is what you want to invoke simple (legacy) blocking code, as shown in your question. There is no reason to involve subprocesses - doing so comes with limitations that only pay off when you need the benefits of better CPU usage through actual parallelism. Creating a custom thread pool is ok but simply unnecessary, the thread pool provided by the event loop will do just  fine.

Comment: what's the difference in the example between `blocking_io` or `cpu_bound` I think my process is more blocking IO and not a number crunching process

Comment: Great, thanks so much @user4815162342. Ill give option #1 a Go

Comment: CPU-bound code is one that does something CPU-intensive, such as machine learning or image processing number crunching. IO-bound code is synchronous code that just waits for something to happen, such as reading from a serial port. As I said, your blocking code appears squarely IO-bound.

Comment: I added one more EDIT for what appears to be working. In the link you sent the example for `run_in_executor` had a `main` function but the code I have been working with does not. Is there anything funny with the way I have my code? It appears to be working... I also found out from the author of the BACnet IO package that the app runs on its own thread too. I added in a comment `#apprently runs on its own thread`

Comment: The link I sent you is just the official asyncio documentation, and it contains a `main()` because that was convenient for that example, not because it's needed for `run_in_executor` to work. Your edited code looks correct, and it can be even shorter, e.g. just `sensor_value = await loop.run_in_executor(bacnet.read, '12345:2 analogInput 2 presentValue')`.

Comment: Also, if you have a fix for the code, please post an answer, or arrange with the commenter to provide one, rather than embedding the answer in the edited question. Providing an answer (and accepting it) will mark your question as resolved.

Comment: Ok great thank you

Comment: One more question @user4815162342 if you dont mind. Can I add in exception handling to the `blocking_io()` function? See edit script (not answer) I did a try and except as this will on occasion error out. Any recommendations for asyncio exception handling? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, exceptions will be propagated through `run_in_executor`. You can just try it yourself. No special "recommendations for asyncio exception handling" are needed, since exceptions propagate naturally through `await` - just use `try`, `except`, `finally`, `with`, as you normally would in Pyhthon.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
import asyncio
from datetime import timedelta
from openleadr import OpenADRClient, enable_default_logging
import BAC0
import concurrent.futures

enable_default_logging()


#apprently runs on its own thread
bacnet = BAC0.lite()


def blocking_io():
    #read temp sensor from BACnet device
    sensor_value = bacnet.read('12345:2 analogInput 2 presentValue')
    return sensor_value


async def collect_report_value():
    # 1. Run in the default loop's executor:
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_io)
    return result



async def handle_event(event):
    # This callback receives an Event dict.
    # You should include code here that sends control signals to your resources.
    return 'optIn'

# Create the client object
client = OpenADRClient(ven_name='ven123',
                       vtn_url='http://localhost:8080/OpenADR2/Simple/2.0b')
```